# "I very like it" is right or wrong?

Tags: word-usage

I heard a lot of non-native speakers said "*I very like it*".

I think "*very*" in this case is adverb and means "*extremely*" [Source](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Avery).

It can be written as "*I extremely like it*".

But I heard that people in some forums think it is wrong [Forum](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic21890.html)

I personally prefer to say "*I really like it*".

SO, "*I very like it*" is right or wrong?

Comment: It's wrong. You could say "I very much like it". "Very" needs to modify another adjective.

Comment: @RoseofWords *Much* here is not acting as an adjective, but an adverb.

Comment: "I very much like it" or "I like it very much"

Comment: @Anonym That is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general we refer to adverbs as a single category, but it's really three different concepts together: *adjective-modifiers*, *verb-modifiers*, and *adverb-modifiers*. Most adverbs can fill all three of these roles, so in English they're conflated into one group. But here you've stumbled onto one of the exceptions.

"Very", "extremely", and a few others can modify adjectives and other adverbs, but they cannot modify verbs directly. So you could say "I very *much* like this", or even use a different adjective-derived adverb as in "I *certainly* like this", but not *"I very like this" or *"I extremely like this".

Comment: Google "*I extremely like it*" in double quotation returns 154000 results & "*I extremely like this*" in double quotation returns 113000 results

Comment: @Tom True, but most of those results are on Facebook, Twitter, Reddit, and other places where ungrammatical phrases are common in informal speech. Searching for "I extremely like it" on Google Books gives only six results: three don't actually seem to contain the phrase, and two of the others are directly quoting non-native speakers. That leaves only one definite instance of its use in the entire Google Books corpus.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you may often hear "I very like" in non native speech is that it is a foreign calque. For example the exact verbatim phrase is quite normal in my language i.e. Polish.